# How do I group icons in the Start menu of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, community-faq-proposed, live-tiles

I love the new start menu of Windows 8 but I would like to be able to organize my icons into sections.  How do I organize my app icons in Windows 8?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy.  Groups are created by dragging an icon in between two other groups (drag up to start the move on tablets):

[image]

Simply organize your icons into the groups that you want.  If you're looking to make the icons smaller you can do that by right-clicking (press and hold or swipe down on tablets) on the icon and select `Smaller`:

[image]

Finally to name groups you have to zoom out (Ctrl+Scroll or Pinch Zoom) and then right click (swiping down) on the group and Select "Name Group":

[image]

There you have it!  A quick and easy way to organize your apps on the "Modern UI".

Comment: You can also click the - button in the bottom right to zoom out :)