# Named Group of tiles (Applications) in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, live-tiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I group icons in the Start menu of Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/484066/how-do-i-group-icons-in-the-start-menu-of-windows-8)

The tiles in Windows 8 ModernUI are just all on that scrolling page (the new "Start Menu"). 
Like the old iOS had several pages, Windows 8 has these third of a page spaces to align the icons/tiles.

But is it possible to make a group/folder of tiles (and maybe even give a group name)? (Like Folders in iOS)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is (for groups at least), see here:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206202822/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/07/win8-howto-10-customize-metro-ui-app-tiles-and-groups.aspx)

---

It looks to be as simple as clicking and dragging, either from a group to another, or to create a group from a group to a new area / empty space.

You can also re-order groups by zooming out (e.g. hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scrolling the mouse wheel, then clicking and dragging it about.

Naming a group is done by zooming out then right clicking, or swiping downwards to get a dialog box to name it.

[image]

---

You can also pin folders to the start screen, as per here http://www.howtogeek.com/107451/how-to-pin-apps-or-folders-to-the-metro-start-screen-in-windows-8/

but that will only open it in explorer.

Comment: Well that's what I already saw, but it's not really a "Folder" with Apps inside and the space is limited to 24 Apps. And I cannot give a name to a group either.

Comment: According to the site you can name groups, but I can't test this now.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using folder/groups interchangeably and am not familiar with iOS folders.