# How do you group Start Menu tiles into categories with headers?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Named Group of tiles (Applications) in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/491513/named-group-of-tiles-applications-in-windows-8)

I've seen pictures of start screens with headings over groups of related tiles like so:

[image]

How is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a new group, left click and drag an icon past the furthest right group. To rename that group:

1. Semantically zoom out. On a computer either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>MouseWheelDown</kbd> or click the `-` sign in the lower right-hand corner.
2. Right click on the group you wish to rename. It will become highlighted with a check-mark. Click `Name group` and enter a name.
   [image]

Comment: I've tried that with all games, or all Adobe, or all Microsoft apps, but the headers don't appear.

Comment: @Louis See my edit

Comment: Ohhh, cool! ^_________^