# group start menu apps

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

The start menu of windows 8 is great,but It has too many items that I want to group them into folders like the start menu folders of windows 7.So for example, I want to have only one entry corresponding to vlc media player which on expanding shows all entries,namely :

- vlc media player
- vlc media player skinned
- reset vlc media player preferences

Is it possible in windows 8.If so how ?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/484066/how-do-i-group-icons-in-the-start-menu-of-windows-8?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/491513/named-group-of-tiles-applications-in-windows-8, http://superuser.com/questions/495209/how-do-you-group-start-menu-tiles-into-categories-with-headers

Comment: here I m not grouping tiles,but the executables of same program.Its like the start menu folders of win 7

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "subfolders" in the Start Screen to be used, it doesn't work that way.

Aside from the related Start Screen grouping questions I linked in the comments, the closest I can come up with is this:

- Create a folder with all the links you want in it (someplace on C:).
- Right click the folder and select "Pin to Start".

This should open the folder of links when you click on it from the Start Screen.

Comment: hmmm,but the folder link will open the folder in file explorer instead of expanding it to show subtimes :(

Comment: Exactly.  There is no expandable sub-folder functionality in the Start Screen, that was kind of one of the main points of difference. :)  If it was there, where would you expect to see a sub-folder's contents, in a whole new Start Screen?