# How can I add a heading to different groups of tiles in the Start Screen?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen, live-tiles

Is there a way to add headings to different groups of tiles in the Windows 8 start screen so that they can be distinguished easily?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Named Group of tiles (Applications) in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/491513/named-group-of-tiles-applications-in-windows-8)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I group icons in the Start menu of Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/484066/how-do-i-group-icons-in-the-start-menu-of-windows-8)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open the Start Screen.
   [image: S1]
2. If you are using a tablet, press two fingers on the screen and move them towards each other. Or, if you are using a mouse, click at the extreme bottom-right corner.
   [image: S2]
3. If you are using a tablet, press the group of tiles and move your finger a bit down. Or, if you are using a mouse then right-click the group of tiles.
   [image: S3]
4. Click `Name Group`.
   [image: S4]
5. Type the name that you want to give to the tile group and click Name.
   [image: S5]
6. That's it.
   [image: S6]