# Windows 8 Start Screen - Moving groups

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

Thanks to [help I've gotten from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/501655/windows-8-start-screen-show-programs-in-order-of-most-frequently-used) I've learned how to create groups of icons on the Windows 8 Start Screen... but how can I move entire groups? I don't want to have to manually drag each icon around from every group.

So for example, how could I switch my Adobe and Microsoft Office groups around without dragging individual icons?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Zoom out by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and mouse scroll wheel, or by clicking the small `[-]` button on the bottom right of the Start screen. Then you can drag groups where you want them.

If you're using multitouch input, you can use pinch to zoom out, and then drag the groups with your finger, just like how you drag tiles around.

Comment: You can also use the small [-] button bottom right (if a mouse is connected) or pinch to zoom out (if you're using a touch device)