# Tiles grouping in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Recently I installed some application which allows me to have multiple virtual desktops in Windows 8. Unfortunatelly when I enter "All apps" I see ~15 tiles to this app. It's very annoying because I have to scroll the menu in order to find other applications. Is there any way to group those tiles in something similiar to folder?

Comment: What application?  And can you provide a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/q/484066/302

Comment: @RowlandShaw Note that Yob's talking about the "All Apps" view, not the main start page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the all apps area, items are grouped, excluding the items pinned to the start menu.

you can right click each one, and it will not show in the 'left hand' part of the menu.

Items in the right part are grouped in folders, so you can do it the old the fashioned way and go and find the 'program files' folder, and add them back in there if you like.

does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

in this folder

> C:\Users\ ... \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\

each sub folder that you create, appears in `All apps` in metro view.

> `to apply it , please restart or log off (sign out).`

Answer (score -1):

You can group them easily by dragging them around between vertical bars (you will see vertical bars just after holding a tile by mouse).

Moreover you can use the little (-) button inside the horizontal scroll bar at right-bottom corner to move groups faster around.

Comment: Yob's talking about the "All Apps" view, rather than the Start page.